# What is karma vipaka and its contents?

Tags: karma, repentance, vipaka

What are the results of various sins done. I heard that it has various kinds of results we get for sins done.

Answer (score 1):

For a puthujjana (ordinary unenlightened person), the results of sinful kamma is rebirth in hell.

> *These beings — who were endowed with bad conduct of body, speech & mind, who reviled noble ones, held wrong views and undertook actions
> under the influence of wrong views — with the break-up of the body,
> after death, have re-appeared in the plane of deprivation, the bad
> destination, the lower realms, in hell.*
>
> *MN 4*

For a Noble One, the results of past sinful kamma is merely *feelings* (*vedana*) *felt* (*vedaniyaṃ*).

> *Bhikkhus, this group [of aggregates] is not yours, nor does it belong
> to others. It is old kamma, to be seen as generated and fashioned by
> volition, as something **to be felt (vedaniyaṃ)***.
>
> *SN 12.37*

AN 3.99 says:

> *Now, a trifling evil deed done by what sort of individual takes him to hell? There is the case where a certain individual is undeveloped in [contemplating] the body, undeveloped in virtue, undeveloped in mind, undeveloped in discernment: restricted, small-hearted, dwelling with suffering. A trifling evil deed done by this sort of individual takes him to hell.*
>
> *Now, a trifling evil deed done by what sort of individual is experienced in the here & now, and for the most part barely appears for a moment? There is the case where a certain individual is developed in [contemplating] the body, developed in virtue, developed in mind, developed in discernment: unrestricted, large-hearted, dwelling with the immeasurable. A trifling evil deed done by this sort of individual is experienced in the here & now, and for the most part barely appears for a moment.*
>
> *Monks, for anyone who says, 'In whatever way a person makes kamma, that is how it is experienced,' there is no living of the holy life,
> there is no opportunity for the right ending of stress.*
>
> *But for anyone who says, 'When a person makes kamma **to be felt (vedanīyaṃ)** in such & such a way, that is how its result is experienced,' **there is
> the living of the holy life**, there is the opportunity for the right
> ending of stress.*

Comment: Comment has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99674/discussion-on-answer-by-dhammadhatu-what-is-karma-vipaka-and-its-contents).

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

See the 2 main MN suttas on Kamma at [MN 135](https://suttacentral.net/mn135/en/bodhi) and [MN 136](https://suttacentral.net/mn136/en/thanissaro). For more detailed infos on Kamma, see accesstoinsight's [index](https://accesstoinsight.org/index-subject.html#kamma)

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You  surely know already. It's simple. Bad actions leads to bad results. Good actions lead to good results.

Like when someone gives from the bottom of their heart, that someone's vipaka is the  development of the bottom of their heart.

Like when someone get's angry,  the vipaka is often anger right back at that someone or that someone looking like a fool.

I'm still finding out the good actions. So I constantly ask myself "What are the good actions?".

Subtle bad actions that we can't even see, the substance of avijja, leads to subtle or substantial bad results.

Death is the vipaka of being compelled to exist or being compelled to not exist on  through
 samsara.

Comment: Thank you for the edit and answer.